# Draw a single line with multiple materials

Tags: javascript, three.js, line

I need to draw 150,000+ lines at a time for meshing on threejs. The quickest way to do so is to add all the vertices and draw the object as a single line:

```
for (var n=0; n < nodeNos.length; n++) {
    var thisNodeNo = nodeNos[n];
    elemGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(meshNodes[thisNodeNo].x, meshNodes[thisNodeNo].y, meshNodes[thisNodeNo].z));        
}

var lineMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
     linewidth: 1,
     color: 0xffffff
});

var line = new THREE.Line(elemGeo, lineMat);
```

I am able to change the color of the line, but as this does not support rgba (I need parts of the line to be transparent) this does not help.

Any ideas how to segment the line with different materials?

Comment: With three.js r.72 and `BufferGeometry.addGroup()`, you can do it. But it is just as easy to render separate lines using `THREE.Line` or `THREE.LineSegments`.

Comment: Can you render separate materials using THREE.LineSegments, or just colors?